Schwab API Trade Python Account Hash
I'm trying to set up an API that allows me to trade stocks via my Schwab account. It seems like Schwab requires me to obtain my account hash first before I can send out any trade orders. I've tried the below Python code to obtain my account hash, but I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error, and this has been happening for a couple of days now.
I'm not sure if this is an internal server issue with Schwab's API or if I'm doing something wrong in my code. Could someone help me check this and provide any tips?
#Code
    import requests
    import json
    import base64

# Log the start of the process

    print("Starting token refresh process...")

# Load tokens from the JSON file

    with open('C:/######/tokens.json') as f:
        tokens = json.load(f)

# Access the refresh and access tokens directly

    refresh_token = tokens['refresh_token']
    access_token = tokens['access_token']

    print("Tokens loaded successfully.")

# Prepare the headers and payload to refresh the token

    client_id = "############################"  # Schwab app key
    client_secret = "###################"  # Schwab app secret

    credentials = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
    base64_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
    
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_credentials}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token": refresh_token
    }
    
    print("Refreshing access token...")

# Refresh the token
    response = requests.post("https://api.schwabapi.com/v1/oauth/token", headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Token refreshed successfully.")
        new_tokens = response.json()
    
        # Save the new tokens
        with open('C:/#################/tokens.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(new_tokens, f)
        print("New tokens saved successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to refresh token. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Error Message: {response.text}")
        exit()
    
# Use the new access token to get account hash
    new_access_token = new_tokens['access_token']
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {new_access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    print("Fetching account hash...")
    
# Make the request to get account hash
    response = requests.get("https://api.schwabapi.com/trader/v1/accounts/accountNumbers", headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        account_data = response.json()
        account_hash = account_data['hashValue']  # Check the correct key
        print(f"Account Hash: {account_hash}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve account hash. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Error Message: {response.text}")

#Console ERROR Message:
C:\#################\main.py 
Starting token refresh process...
Tokens loaded successfully.
Refreshing access token...
Token refreshed successfully.
New tokens saved successfully.
Fetching account hash...
Failed to retrieve account hash. Status Code: 400
Error Message: 
            { "errors": [ { "id": "5ce0a10c-b84a-733b-c46f-7b773fae7d59", "status": 500, "title": "Internal Server Error" } ] }
        

Process finished with exit code 0


was it working previously ?    have you reached out to Schwab tech support ?  , check out https://pypi.org/project/schwab-api/

Can you please share the code you use to obtain the refresh and access tokens?
